# Why BufferedReader gives me exception When it found nothing

Tags: android, string, bufferedreader

I am writing an application for the Android platform.  My purpose is; I search the word that I wrote on edit text from a text file. To make this; I used to BufferedReader. ( Txt file size too high so that I used to edit custom properties). My code is working perfectly when It found my word in a text file. But When I search meanless something like 'asdsad'. My code gives me the exception. It is about BufferedReader How can I fix it?

custom properties:

```
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=999999
```

My codes:

```
String text = "";
        BufferedReader reader;

        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("word_families_kopya.txt");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line = reader.readLine();

            String translating_string = editText_words.getText().toString();


while (!line.contains(translating_string) && line.toString() != null) {


    line = reader.readLine();
```

Log.i(TAG, "onClick: " + line);
        cevirilmis_textview.setText(line);

```
}


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {

    }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {

        }
```

Exception message:

> read: unexpected EOF!

Comment: Your `String line = reader.readLine();` is `null`

Comment: This is impossible. I am writing in edit text and search for it. İf I write a word that in the text file. It works. But I write a word that doesn't in the text file. It gives me the exception.

Comment: You can see my question. I editted ıt. And It still gives me the exception.

Comment: Try this  `while (!line.contains(translating_string) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(line))`

Comment: It works. I am so thanks for your help. But I have still little bit problem in my mind. What is the 'TextUtils' and Why did you mark my question with  'What is a NullPointerException,'? I do not ask NullPointerException.

Comment: you have removed crash log from your question  check the revision history here https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51946814/2

Comment: ok. I get it. Thanks for your helping.

Comment: Welcome happy to help you